# How to connect apache superset directly with google BigQuery?

Tags: apache-superset

I am running Apache superset on GCP instance and it works fine with Sqlite database which is default in superset and I don't need to configure so many things. But my requirement is that I need superset to connect directly with BigQuery instead of Sqlite and I don't have developer background. So, is there an easy way to do that without heavy codes?

Comment: Can you comment on what you tried so far? It will be much easier to help you then.

Comment: I ran superset on python virtual environment (venv) and I already installed "pybigquery". But when I try to connect to bigquery by typing "bigquery://", it shows the error like this "ERROR: {"error": "Connection failed!\n\nThe error message returned was:\n(pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)"}"

Answer (score 4):

Connecting to BigQuery is very well documented here in Preset's Superset user documentation https://docs.preset.io/docs/big-query-database

Comment: The question is about superset, not preset

Answer (score 3):

Following the steps mentioned at the official Google Cloud page [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started), you need to do the following

1. Install pybigquery

```
pip install pybigquery
```

2. Download your Google Cloud authorization `json` key file
3. From your terminal instance, set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env. var to the path of your `json` key file

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/[json_file].json"
```

Answer (score 0):

Elbehery is right. I don't have enough rep to comment, but I wanted to note that [Apache has created docs for this](https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/bigquery/#google-bigquery).

FWIW, I couldn't use the UI for importing `credentials.json` so I set it as an env var in my Docker image. Here are the commands and steps I run locally:

```
# Setup virtual environment (exit by typing "deactivate")
pip3 install virtualenv
python3 -m virtualenv ./.venv
source ./.venv/bin/activate
​
# Download Superset
git clone https://github.com/apache/superset.git
cd superset/
​
# Create a copy of your credentials for docker to use
cp ~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json docker/credentials.json
echo "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=docker/credentials.json" >> docker/.env-non-dev
​
# Run Superset
docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml pull
docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up
​
```

Now that `Superset` is running locally:

- visit http://0.0.0.0:8088/ in your web browser
- In the top right of UI, click the `+DATABASE` button (or `+` > `Data` > `Connect Database`)
- In popup window Click `Supported Databases` then (at the bottom) `Other`
- Set `DISPLAY NAME: BigQuery`
- Set `SQLALCHEMY URI: bigquery://my_project_id`
- Click `Test Connection`
- Click `Connect`
  ​
  Now that BigQuery is integrated into Superset:
- In the top of page Click `SQL Lab` > `SQL Editor`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31583051)

Comment: > This does not provide an answer to the question.

@erikced What do you mean by this? He said he was hosting on a GCP instance, which is vague but implies he is running a Docker container hosted by GCP.

I offered repeatable steps which allow you to integrate SuperSet with BQ via a docker container. Its a containerized solution that can be deployed anywhere.